# Change JLabel Text without click on Button

Tags: java, swing, label, frame

I am creating a quiz and I missed the labels with a transition text. I want the labels with the question and answers to be changed when the program starts. So it would not make sense to change the labels with a button. I would only do that after the first question.

Comment: You create a method like `nextQuestion()`. You invoke this method when you create the frame and you invoke the method when the first question is answered.

Comment: If you want the change text after a certain period use swing `Timer`